# Removing all the files in a branch with git?

Tags: git, git-rm

Trying to run `git rm -r *` on a branch.  I have `dist` in `.gitignore`, but still get this error:

> fatal: pathspec 'dist' did not match any files

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this error because `*` is actually interpolated by your shell into the list of all files; git doesn't know you're trying to use a wildcard. `git rm -r .` ("delete all files recursively, starting from this folder") should work instead.